# Server send notification to Android Phone

Tags: android

I would like to create a instant message application. The problem I faced is that how can I know other has sent a message to me and my mobile can get a notification from server?

Comment: you can start by reading this:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html

Comment: if my application is written by PhoneGap, is it possible to do this?

Comment: yes, please refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878229/c2dm-phonegap-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Developing  Client side Application is must to notify the Update from server, 
Have to run the back ground [services](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html) continuously  to find the update.

If you are accessing the android inbox message , no need to create the own service , we can use the android service here